# How do you find nearest pairs between sets without using O(N*M) memory?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two sets of vectors A (red) and B (blue). I'm looking to find the nearest vector in A to each point in B.

[image]

I got this working using:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def get_assignment(A, B):
    """
    returns `assignment`, where `assignment[i]` means A[assignment[i]] is the nearest point to B[i]
    """
    cost = np.linalg.norm(A[:, np.newaxis, :] - B, axis=2)
    assignment = np.argmin(cost, axis=0)
    return assignment

if __name__ == '__main__':
    An = 3
    Bn = 10
    A = np.array([ [ random.random(), random.random() ] for i in range(An) ]) 
    B = np.array([ [ random.random(), random.random() ] for i in range(Bn) ]) 
    assignment = get_assignment(A, B)

    import pylab

    for i in range(len(A)):
        Bi = np.where(assignment == i)[0]
        for j in Bi:
            x1, y1 = A[i]
            x2, y2 = B[j]
            pylab.plot(x1, y1, 'ro')
            pylab.plot(x2, y2, 'bo')
            pylab.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'k-', lw=0.5)

    pylab.axis('equal')
    pylab.show()
```

But I'm looking to do this where A has around 1,000 elements and B 1,000,000. Is there a way to do this using less memory?

Comment: The distance function is only 1-dimensional? Calculate midpoints of set A and use them to partition vectors B.

Comment: @Kache The vectors in A and B can be arbitrary 3D vectors. I'll update the example

Comment: Would `NearestNeighbors` in `sklearn.neighbors` help? Or perhaps a voronoi tesselation using points A and then figuring out what regions points B fall into?

Comment: Take from game programming techniques for detecting collisions in 2/3D. Multi-phased approach where the world is partitioned into chunks, and you only search nearby chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest applying a [K-D tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import sklearn.neighbors


def get_assignment(A, B):
    """
    returns `assignment`, where `assignment[i]` means A[assignment[i]] is the nearest point to B[i]
    """
    tree = sklearn.neighbors.KDTree(A)
    assignment = tree.query(B, return_distance=False).reshape(-1)
    return assignment


if __name__ == '__main__':
    An = 1000
    Bn = 1000000

    A = np.random.rand(An, 2)
    B = np.random.rand(Bn, 2)
    assignment = get_assignment(A, B)
```

Measuring this using `/usr/bin/time -v`, it takes roughly 36 MB to do this query. It's also much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
def get_assignment_low_memory(A, B, window=10000):
    """
    returns `assignment`, where `assignment[i]` means A[assignment[i]] is the nearest point to B[i]
    """
    assignment = []
    for i in range(0, len(B), window):
        print(i, len(B))
        C = B[i:i+window]
        cost = np.linalg.norm(A[:, np.newaxis, :] - C, axis=2)
        assignment += np.argmin(cost, axis=0).tolist()
    return np.array(assignment)
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `numpy`, but I think you're searching chunks (windows) too greedily? Points near the boundary of its own chunk could be closer to points of an adjacent chunk than to other points within the same chunk.

Comment: It's always considering all points in A for each chunk.